# Numpy: How to access elements beside elements satisfying condition

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

First off let me apologize for any formatting issues, I am writing this on a phone. If I had an numpy array 'a' I could easily find all values of 'a' satisfying elem > 2 via:

```
a = no.random.random_sample(10)
idx = a > 2
a[idx]
```

my question is how I would access the elements on the right hand side of the elements satisfying the condition in a fast and pythonic manner. So if 'a' satisfies the condition at indices 1,2,4,7, I want to have access to the array at indices 2,3,5,8.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use `numpy.where` to get the indices where `idx` is `True`:

```
>>> np.where(idx)[0]
array([1, 2, 4, 7])
```

Add `1` to that array (or any other operation):

```
>>> new_idx = np.where(idx)[0] + 1
>>> new_idx
array([2, 3, 5, 8])
```

And then slice using that:

```
>>> a[new_idx]
```

Comment: Thanks, can this also be done for a 2D array (lets say I wanted the values underneath)? Would I just add nx? Also is it possible to force np to use preallocated memory when assigning the index array?

Comment: Yes, 2D should also work. In that case `where` will return a tuple, so you might have to convert it into a numpy array before doing any operations on it. --- What do you mean by "preallocated memory"? Like just hard coded indices?

Comment: In C for example, you would pass a memory location to the routine that returned the index array and the index array would be allocated at that location. If you have to allocate a new array each time you request the index array, it will be very inefficient.

Comment: No, you can't pass a preallocated array/memory to `where`. Even if you could how would you know how big to make it? The overhead of allocating a contiguous block of memory is negligible compared to all the other stuff the Python interpreter has to allocate for a function call.